# Why justify-content doesn't work but align-items work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have put this code on the board class to organize the < div > in the class.

```
.board{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

However the justify content doesn't work... both div inside board class glued each other. but the align-items and flex-flow works well, why justify-content doesn't?

[Here is my website looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrMqY.png)

my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <header>
            <h1>Draw clues about the music playing </h1> <img src="images/v94_61.png">
        </header>

        <div class="board">
            <div class="color-board">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>

                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>

            <div class="drawer">
            </div>
            <div class="tool-board">
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

my css code:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(218, 210, 153, 1), rgba(176, 218, 185, 1));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: center;

    border: 3px solid rgba(76, 121, 60, 1);
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    border-radius: 1.75em;
    background-color:rgba(131, 131, 131, 0.4000000059604645);
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    padding: 0px 5%;
}

header img {
    width: "fit-content";
    height: 90px;
}

header h1 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 270px;
}

.board{
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.color-board{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(131, 131, 131, 0.4000000059604645);
    width: 100px;
    height: fit-content;
}

.color-board div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background-color: white;
}

.drawer{
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid rgba(76, 121, 60, 1);
    border-radius: 1em;
    width: 732px;
    height: 352px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code so we can figure out whats wrong.

Comment: we also need the html code to help you

Comment: Just ensure `.board` has width greater than the sum of the width of the both the child div element

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: May I know what is your desired output

Comment: https://web-platform-anyjem.stackblitz.io/me.html - It is working as expected. There are spaces between the three child elements.

Comment: @Viira I wish the justify-content: space-around; to worked at the color-board class.

Comment: @schoolcoder when I try to open that it never displays just keep loading...